# Do SPY prices include dividends?

Tags: dividends, rate-of-return, dividend-reinvestment

I'd like to calculate the return of SPY over a range of time. For example:

```
5/1/18: 264.98
9/14/18: 290.88

264.98 - 290.88 = 25.9
25.9/264.98= 0.0977 = 9.77%
```

Does the 9.77% return include SPY dividends?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No it does not. Indices that *do* included dividends in their price should be labelled as "total return" indices.

To be certain, looking at the history on [Yahoo](https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/SPY/history?period1=1521262800&period2=1537160400&interval=1d&filter=history&frequency=1d), the actual 5/1 closing price of 264.98 was adjusted down for the dividend that occurred on 6/15. So you'd need to increase your ending point by the amount of the dividend (or use the adjusted 5/1 price) to calculate "total return".

Here's an example with your numbers. You already calculated the return from 5/1/18 to 9/14/18 at 9.77%. However, you *also* received a 1.246 dividend in that period, so your total return is

```
(290.88 + 1.246 - 264.98) / 264.98 = 10.24%
```

Rather than listing the dividends earned in each period to add to the end price, Yahoo (and other data vendors) instead adjust the *beginning* price by the amount of dividends paid *after* that price. So using their adjusted price on 5/1 of 263.80, you could also calculate the return as

```
(290.88 - 263.80) / 263.80 = 10.27%
```

Note that the return is not *exactly* the same since the denominator is different, but should be close enough for return comparisons.

Comment: I see they listed the adjusted price, which does not include the dividend right? Doesn't that mean close prices do include the dividend? If that is the case and since I'm using close prices, I should be fine.

Comment: The adjusted price _accounts for_ the dividend. The price of an index drops by the amount of the dividend, so the adjusted price reflects that drop. The closing price represents the _actual closing price_ on that date. Adjusted prices are used to easily calculate _total return_.

Comment: If you are calculating prices off of the adjusted price, you aren't accounting for dividends. How is that total return? Aren't dividends included in total return?

Comment: Think about it this way - if nothing had happened except the dividend, on 6/15 the price would go from 283.73 (actual price) to 277.48 (adjusted price), reflecting a drop in price when in fact the drop was because of a dividend. If you use the adjusted price for 6/14, there would be no price change so your _total return_ would be 0.

Comment: @D Stanley - "If nothing had happened except the dividend, on 6/15 the price would go from 283.73 (actual price) to 277.48 (adjusted price)."  TYPO ?

Comment: @BobBaerker Yes - should have been 278.73 instead of 283.73. Thanks

Comment: @DStanley: How does a dividend paid on 6/15 effect a price on 5/1? Also, the price didn't change on 6/15 for the dividend. It changed on 6/14: 278.73 - 277.48 = 1.25. I'm looking for SPY returns based on reinvested dividends. I'm using VOO and reinvesting dividends and want to compare against SPY. I was assuming dividends are reinvested with SPY but I guess not. This has gotten overly confusing.

Comment: It doesn't affect the _actual_ price. The _adjusted_ price is just used to show what the price _would_ have been if the dividend had been paid before that date so you can account for it in return calculations. It's easier than posting total dividends paid to date to do total return calculations.

Comment: The bottom line is that no, SPY does not include dividends.

Comment: If VOO is reinvesting dividends but SPY is not, how can I possibly compare returns? They seem incompatible.

Comment: You compare _total_ returns. For spy you calculate total return by adding in dividends paid in the period. Or using adjusted prices if you have them.

Comment: Do you at least have a calculation can you show for the period mentioned? Otherwise, it's just running around in circles.

Comment: Suppose you bot stock @ $100 yesterday. Ex-div for $1 today. Stock exchange reduces share price by $1 and if no opening B/S imbalance,  stock will open at $99. You sell and  incur $1 loss on stock but you'll receive $1 on Pay Date (-1 +1 = 0).  Total Return is ZERO (ignoring commissions and any tax biite if non sheltered.  OTOH, you could bypass the dividend and just use the adjusted data for calculation. You paid $100 but after adjustment it's $99 which you can sell for $99 today and Total return is again ZERO.  Wouldn't matter if it was sold for $99 today or $99 next month.Tot Ret is ZERO

Comment: @DStanley: Based on your updated answer, it looks like this goes all the way back to what I had mentioned before: Just use adjusted close prices if you want to factor in the dividend.

Comment: @4thSpace Correct.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the difference between the 9/14 close and the actual close on 5/01 and add the  dividend received.

Or you can use the difference between the 9/14 close and the adjusted close on 5/01.

And if it makes your life any easier, you can use the DRIP calculator at:

https://www.dividendchannel.com/drip-returns-calculator/

Comment: Is that calculator correct? Every time I compare a high dividend index fund (SCHD or SPYD) to the S&P 500 index fund, it always says the S&P 500 index fund had more dividend cash per share reinvested. It seems counter-intuitive that a high dividend index fund does not actually have high dividends.

Comment: @JoJo: SCHD trades at $53, SPY at $289.  I expect the latter to pay out a larger dividend in absolute terms, but a smaller one in relative terms.  Which are you talking about when you say "more dividend cash per share"?

Comment: The benchmark for SCHD is the Dow Jones U.S. Dividend 100 Index.  The benchmark for SPYD is the S&P 500 High Dividend Index and is designed to measure the performance of the top 80 dividend yielding securities.  You're comparing apples and oranges.

Comment: That's the problem with these calculators and why I'm trying to do it manually but no one knows.

Comment: The calculator that I provided provides the same results that you provided in your question.